# I can't access dockerized angular app using base url

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm new to docker. I integrated my infrastructure this way. I rapped my angular 4 project inside nginx image. I'm using nginx also as reverse proxy between between angular project and api. I want to access my application using url `http://localhost:9000/system` but i can only do `http://localhost:9000`.  After running this

```
docker run -p 9000:80 -dit nginx
```

I tried to build my angular app `ng build --prod --base-href /system`, and changed `<base href='/system'/>`. Its working on my development machine fine but when i rap inside docker i can only access `http://localhost:9000` and worse i can't access the application after refreshing the browser.

Dockerfile

```
# Set the base image to nginx
FROM nginx
COPY nginx /usr/share/nginx/html
# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

 server {

        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        root pos;
        index index.html index.htm;

    location /api/service {

                # Preflighted requests
                if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, DELETE";
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
                add_header "Access-Control-Max-Age" 1728000;
                #add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" true;
                add_header "Content-Type" "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
                add_header "Content-Length" 0;
                return 204;
            } 
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
```

Comment: What about your nginx.conf could you update the post with it and dockerfile also.

Comment: I updated those files as shown above. nginx i ignored api routes configuration.

Comment: There is no `/system` location in your nginx config?